# How to simplify OLS formulas?

Tags: least-squares

Let $\lbrace x_i,y_i\rbrace_{i=1}^n$ be a random sample.  I am trying to simplify the following expression

$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i - n \bar{X}\bar{Y}}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 -n\bar{X}^2}$$
to show it equals $$\frac{S_{xy}}{S_x^2}$$

I've been manipulating this for almost 2 hours and haven't made any progress.

How can I simplify the first expression to yield the second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. Observe that
$$
\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i - n \bar{x}\bar{y}}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 -n\bar{x}^2}
=\frac{\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i - \bar{x}\bar{y}}{\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 -\bar{x}^2}\tag1 $$ then we are left with proving that
$$
S_x^2=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n \left(x_i -\bar{x}\right)^2=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 -\bar{x}^2 \tag2
$$ and that
$$
S_{xy}=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n \left(x_i -\bar{x}\right)\left(y_i -\bar{y}\right)=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i -\bar{x}\bar{y}. \tag3
$$

Let's see how to prove $(2)$. We have
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n \left(x_i -\bar{x}\right)^2&=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n \left(x^2_i -2x_i\bar{x}+\bar{x}^2\right)
\\\\&=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n x^2_i -2\bar{x}\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nx_i+\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n\bar{x}^2
\\\\&=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n x^2_i -2\:\bar{x}\times \bar{x}+\frac1n \times n\:\bar{x}^2
\\\\&=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n x^2_i -\bar{x}^2.
\end{align}
$$ Similarly one gets $(3)$.

Thus, from $(1)$ we obtain
$$
\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i - n \bar{x}\bar{y}}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 -n\bar{x}^2}
=\frac{\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i - \bar{x}\bar{y}}{\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 -\bar{x}^2}=\frac{\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n \left(x_i -\bar{x}\right)\left(y_i -\bar{y}\right)}{\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n \left(x_i -\bar{x}\right)^2}=\frac{S_{xy}}{S_x^2}.\tag4
$$

Comment: Ahhhh! Thank you so much! I had most of it, but made a silly arithmetic error in proving step 2. Accepted!

Comment: @StanShunpike You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

divide top and bottom by n.

this gives you

$\dfrac{\frac{1}{n}\sum x_iy_i-E[X]E[Y]} {\frac{1}{n}\sum x_i^2-E[X]^2}$

Now let's look at the defintion of Variance.

$\frac{1}{n}\sum (x_i-E[X])^2 =$$ \frac{1}{n}\sum (x_i^2-2x_iE[X]+E[X]^2)\\
\frac{1}{n}\sum x_i^2- E[X]\frac{1}{n}\sum 2x_i+E[X]^2\\
\frac{1}{n}\sum x_i^2- 2E[X]^2+E[X]^2)\\
\frac{1}{n}\sum x_i^2- E[X]^2$

Now perform similar algebra to show that:
$\frac{1}{n}\sum (x_i-E[X])(y_i-E[Y]) = \frac{1}{n}\sum x_iy_i-E[X]E[Y]$